# What constitutes Date Usage on an iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5 and I just received notice that my data usage for free is almost up.  I presently have 1GB. I am total unaware of what data usage is and should I change to a plan with 2GB.

Do I have to do something to make sure I use Wi-Fi in all places that I am.

Exactly what takes up my data usage when using my phone? Is it from receiving a message, text, taking photos. Please be specific if possible.

Comment: Also, please take a look at this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4162/how-to-stop-an-iphone-3g-from-using-cell-data-ever?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Linda - feel free to edit this to be "how do I shut off all data access" if that's the real question. You can then just see what works and what doesn't and not need to pay for any more data until next month's allotment arrives.

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact your Carrier, i.e. Verizon, AT&T, Sprint etc, to see what they define as Data Usage.

That said, generally speaking, any communication that you send/receive/request over their network while directly connected to their network, and while Roaming, is typically counted under Data Usage.  This could be emails, websites, pictures, videos, etc. Typically when connected to a Wi-Fi Access Point then Data Usage Accounting is not counted against your monthly Data Usage allotment.

Answer (score 0):

Really, data usage is anything that do over the internet when not connected to a Wi-Fi network, when you're on your iPhone's cellular connection. Email, web browsing, YouTube, even iMessage, games played online, almost anything that requires an internet connection all consume data. If you want to consume less data try not to watch online videos over a cellular connection and always connect to your home Wi-Fi network.